# Own toJSON places object object in localstorage

Tags: json, angular, typescript, local-storage

I need my logged in user and to keep getting him even after refreshes, I place his values into the local storage. When I use JSON.stringify(), it places the correct values in the local storage but with _ in front of the key names and I don't know why (I named my private properties _id e.g. but I wrote getters and I think that should name them normally again right?). Because it didn't work, I've written my own toJSON method:

```js
toJSON(): any {
    return {
      id: this._id,
      firstName: this._firstName,
      lastName: this._lastName,
      email: this._email,
      phoneNumber: this._phone,
      country: this._country,
      comments: this._comments.map(c => c.toJSON)
    };
```

but when I call this one, it places [object Object]  into the local storage and I can't figure ou why it would do that.

I basically need to either make it that JSON.stringify places my attribute in the localStorage or I need to fix my toJson.

#### User model:

```
import { Comment } from '../image/comment.model';

export class User {
  constructor(
    private _id: number,
    private _firstName: string,
    private _lastName: string,
    private _email: string,
    private _phone: string,
    private _country: string,
    private _comments: Comment[]
  ) {}

  get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  get firstName(): string {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  get lastName(): string {
    return this._lastName;
  }

  get email(): string {
    return this._email;
  }

  get phone(): string {
    return this._phone;
  }

  get country(): string {
    return this._country;
  }

  get comments(): Comment[] {
    return this._comments;
  }

  static fromJSON(json: any): User {
    return new User(
      json.id,
      json.firstName,
      json.lastName,
      json.email,
      json.phoneNumber,
      json.country,
      json.comments
    );
  }

  toJSON(): any {
    return {
      id: this._id,
      firstName: this._firstName,
      lastName: this._lastName,
      email: this._email,
      phoneNumber: this._phone,
      country: this._country,
      comments: this._comments.map(c => c.toJSON)
    };
  }
}
```

#### authentication service

```js
this.getUser(email).subscribe(usr => { //this gets my user via its email from the backend
              localStorage.setItem('visitor', usr.toJSON());
              this._loggedInUser$.next(usr);
            });

this._loggedInUser$ = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
      localStorage.getItem('visitor')
        ? User.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('visitor'))
        : null
    );

  get loggedInUser$(): BehaviorSubject<User> {
    return this._loggedInUser$;
  }
```

#### Comment

```js
export class Comment {
  private _id: number;
  constructor(
    private _author: string,
    private _content: string,
    private _date: Date,
    private _imageId: number,
    private _visitorId: number
  ) {}

  get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }
  set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  get author(): string {
    return this._author;
  }

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }

  get date(): Date {
    return this._date;
  }

  get imageId(): number {
    return this._imageId;
  }

  get visitorId(): number {
    return this._visitorId;
  }

  static fromJSON(json: any): Comment {
    let comment = new Comment(
      json.author,
      json.content,
      json.date,
      json.myImageId,
      json.visitorId
    );
    comment.id = json.id;
    return comment;
  }

  toJSON(): any {
    return {
      id: this._id,
      author: this._author,
      content: this._content,
      date: this._date,
      myImageId: this._imageId,
      visitorId: this._visitorId
    };
  }
}
```

If any more code is needed, just let me know!

Comment: You seem to be coding Typescript like it's Java. There is no need for all of the class private member variables, and getters. You're reinventing the wheel when it comes to stringifying/parsing an object. Your `toJSON()` functions return objects, not JSON, which seems to be your issue in this post. Was you plan to create these functions in all of your classes? Do you really want that?

Comment: @R.Richards we've learn't that this is a best practice at school (private attributes and public getters that is)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you have given the variables the same name as the JSON object property names. If you want to get rid of the underscores try providing the variables with some different names.

Comment: isn't this the easiest to get them back out of json?

Comment: Yes it is. Because this helps you to save the time spent in choosing between the underscored properties as well as to maintain clean code